# PHP- Turning a String to Array with RegEx statement

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm getting this string which I can't control:

```
$string = '[{"val":"agent,,james,,89","number":0,"dID":0}, {"val":"house,,Villa,,389m","number":1,"dID":2}]';
```

Would like to only collect the `val` and put them into an array where they are separated by the two commas

End results:

```
var_dump($resArr) // Array [{"agent", "james", "89"}, {"house", "villa", "389m"}]
```

What I've done so far:

```
$string = '[{"val":"agent,,james,,89","number":0,"dID":0}, {"val":"house,,Villa,,389m","number":1,"dID":2}]';

parse_str(stripslashes(str_replace(["'=>'","','"],['=','&'],trim($string,"'"))),$form_data);

var_dump($form_data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your initial string is JSON, you can easily parse it with `json_decode()`. Then just iterate through the array and `explode()` the `"val"` by the delimiter `,,` and add it to an array.

```
<?php

$string = '[{"val":"agent,,james,,89","number":0,"dID":0}, {"val":"house,,Villa,,389m","number":1,"dID":2}]';

$json = json_decode($string, true);
$output = [];
foreach($json as $elm)
{
    $val = $elm["val"];
    $words = explode(",,", $val);
    $output[] = $words;
}

var_dump($output);
?>
```

This gives $output a value of

```
[["agent", "james", "89"], ["house", "villa", "389m"]]
```

[Demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/616ad6f4d7a538231d047ed1873388762e1ba313)

Answer (score 0):

You have an accepted answer, but I was bored:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) {
                        return explode(',,', $v['val']);
                    }, json_decode($string, true));
```